# How do you delete the first few items from an array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, boolean

I have a method that takes in a string array and finds the averages of every few items depending on the length.  I would like the method to delete the first few items in the array depending on the value of offset.

```
public static double[] getMovingAverage(String[] priceList, int length, int offset){

    double[] newPriceList = convert(priceList);

    int listLength = newPriceList.length;
    int counter = 0;
    double listsum;
    double[] movingAverage = new double[listLength];

    try{
        for (int aa = 0; aa < listLength-1; aa++){
            listsum = 0;
            for (int bb = 0; bb < length; bb++){
                counter = aa+bb;

                listsum = listsum + newPriceList[counter];
            }
            movingAverage[aa] = listsum / length;
        }
        if (offset>0){

                        //remove first #offset# elements

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return movingAverage;
}
```

*note: convert(); converts String[] to double[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are fixed-length in Java. (You can't change the length of an array.)

You can however create a new array with the first `offset` elements removed quite easily:

```
double[] movingAverage = { 0.1, 0.2, 1.1, 1.2 };
int offset = 2;

// print before
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(movingAverage));

// remove first offset elements
movingAverage = Arrays.copyOfRange(movingAverage, offset, movingAverage.length);

// print after
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(movingAverage));
```

**Output:**

```
[0.1, 0.2, 1.1, 1.2]
[1.1, 1.2]
```

Answer (score 2):

From Java 6 API

> public static double[]
>   copyOfRange(double[] original,
>                                      int from,
>                                      int to)
>
> Copies the specified range of the
>   specified array into a new array. The
>   initial index of the range (from) must
>   lie between zero and original.length,
>   inclusive. The value at original[from]
>   is placed into the initial element of
>   the copy (unless from ==
>   original.length or from == to). Values
>   from subsequent elements in the
>   original array are placed into
>   subsequent elements in the copy. The
>   final index of the range (to), which
>   must be greater than or equal to from,
>   may be greater than original.length,
>   in which case 0d is placed in all
>   elements of the copy whose index is
>   greater than or equal to
>   original.length - from. The length of
>   the returned array will be to - from.
>
> Parameters: original - the array from
>    which a range is to be copied from -
>    the initial index of the range to be
>    copied, inclusive to - the final index
>    of the range to be copied, exclusive.
>    (This index may lie outside the
>    array.)
>
> Returns: a new array
>   containing the specified range from
>   the original array, truncated or
>   padded with zeros to obtain the
>   required length
>
> Throws:
>   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - if
>   from < 0 or from > original.length()
>   IllegalArgumentException - if from >
>   to NullPointerException - if original
>   is null Since:
>   1.6

Comment: This is a good answer; too bad one does not find it when searching for "shift Java array" -- perhaps this comment could help in that respect?

Answer (score 2):

instead of deleting items, why not just create a new list of the smaller size as output, and always use index-offset as the index into it?

Comment: Yes.  And initialize aa to offset while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the Arrays.copyOfRange() methods would do?

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(boolean[], int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can't explicitly delete from an array, but you can use another data-structure, like an ArrayList, to accumulate the results.  In your case, though, you might just want to change the code to size the array correctly ie.

```
 double[] movingAverage = new double[listLength-offset];
```

and

```
    for (int aa = 0; aa < listLength-offset; aa++){
```

Comment: if you want to do that you need to start your for-loop from _offset_ and not 0 and you will need to iterate over the first offset elements to calculate their sum, otherwise your calculation of the running average would be incorrect

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the copying of the arrays, you could use a collections class like LinkedList that have O(1) remove operations from the head.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html